# Dynamic spreedsheet ID in html file

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, google-visualization

I'm using a gs to display a chart, the data I use, is from the same spreadsheet:

```
function ruptureTraca() {
  var ui = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('ChartLine').setWidth(1350).setHeight(550);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(ui,"Evolution Backlog");
  
}
```

the ChartLine html file looks like :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
     google.charts.load("current", {packages: ["corechart", "line"]});
     google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
     function drawChart() {
var query = new google.visualization.Query(
          'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/[spreadSheet_ID]/edit?sheet=for%20Graph&headers=1');
...
```

i'd like to add the spreadsheet's id as a variable, something like :

```js
var query = new google.visualization.Query(
          'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/' + id + '/edit?sheet=for%20Graph&headers=1');
```

in order to copy the file and chart function would be able to get data from the new spreadsheet not the original.

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please add a brief description of your search/research efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Answer (score 1):

you could add the id to the `drawChart` function as an argument...

```
 function drawChart(id) {
   var query = new google.visualization.Query(
      'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/' + id + '/edit?sheet=for%20Graph&headers=1');
```

then call as many times as you have ids...

```
 google.charts.load("current", {packages: ["corechart", "line"]});
 google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(function () {
   drawChart(id_1);
   drawChart(id_2);
 });
```